# What is the meaning of special character sequences like `\027[0K`?

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape, terminfo

I found [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/infer/commit/0bf96666397a1ea03a2b683419b2a4c66c1195f6#diff-fe18c329702773a28e530784bd6f5c9dR51) from facebook infer, and I have no idea what `\027[0K` and `\027[%iA` means.
What does these special string mean? And (I think) if there are more strings like this, where can I find the full documentation about this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: What makes you think this related to `bash`? The code you linked to is written in OCaml.

Comment: @chepner I know it is written in OCaml, but the purpose of that code snippet is to draw a task bar in the shell.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, I will read that page. I think the code is related to ANSI Terminal, so I think the page name "ANSI escape code" is what I need!

Comment: @sangwoo-joh No, the purpose is to display something in the terminal. Terminal != shell.

Comment: @chepner Oh, thanks for your correction. I'm afraid I'm not aware of the difference between the terminal and shell. Is shell an element of terminal?

Comment: The terminal is an interface that provides input (via the keyboard) and output (to the screen). You can use it to interact with any program. The shell is command interpreter that makes it easy to run other commands, and it is just one program that can run in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Those are escape sequences to tell your terminal what to do.
For example, the sequence of characters represented by `\027[0K` (where `\027` is ASCII decimal value for `Esc` character) tells the terminal to "clear line from cursor to the end."
One helpful document/guide on this subject can be found at https://shiroyasha.svbtle.com/escape-sequences-a-quick-guide-1

Comment: Thank you. This explanation helps me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The facebook code is copied from another source [here](https://github.com/Chris00/ANSITerminal/blob/master/src/ANSITerminal_unix.ml), which uses hard-coded formatters imitating termcap ([this page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tctest.html) gives some background).  The original has comments indicating where its information came from.

The formatter uses "%i" for integers.  That's a repeat-count for the cursor movement "cursor-up" <kbd>`\033[A`</kbd>

In most languages, `\033` (octal) is used for the ASCII escape character.  But this source (according to the [github analysis](https://github.com/Chris00/ANSITerminal)) is written in [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.05/htmlman/lex.html), and is using the *decimal* value for the ASCII escape character.  According to the OCaml syntax, you could use an octal value like this: <kbd>`\o033`</kbd>

Once you see that the formatting parts (how the escape character is represented, the use of `%i` to format a number), the rest of this is documented in several places.

- The relevant standard is [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)
- the termcap (or analogous terminfo) information is in the [terminal database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#toc-_V_T100__A_N_S_I__I_S_O_6429__E_C_M_A-48__P_C-_T_E_R_M__T_E_R_M_I_N_A_L__S_T_A_N_D_A_R_D_S).